How to detect the voltage of Tx and Rx lines of USB
I need to build a circuit that would be able to detect the voltage in the Tx and Rx lines of the USB.
I have used a multimeter to check the voltage whenever there is a data flow and it's about 1 volts.
So, how to indicate that using an LED indicator?

Why do you want to do this?

This sounds a lot like this question.  I'm guessing you want to see it for fun to see if data is being transferred.  My observation last summer was such things are possible but you may not be pleased with the result.

I want this to know which USB storage device is active. Do you have the circuit for this?
